# ¿Como ejecutar SaveChange al fallar en un Try y Guardarlo en un Catch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework, excepciones

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, utilizo `try` y `catch` para controlar las excepciones, estas misma excepciones quiero guardarlas en mi BD, para tener un log, el problema es que en mi `try` tengo un código y coloco un dato erróneo para que falle en `SaveChange()`, y cuando vaya al `catch` guarde mi error. Pero falla en el `SaveChange()` del `catch` por el error del try.

Es decir en `try`  fallo porque viola la llave foránea de mi tabla test

En el `catch` me trae el mismo mensaje fallo porque viola la llave foránea de mi tabla test cuando allí la tabla es otra

Intente utilizar `Using` para que en ese bloque guarde el error, pero sigue arrastrando la `excepcion` de `try`.

Espero hayan comprendido y me den alguna sugerencia para evitar este error

**Código**

```
        var result= string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            context.test.Add(test);
            context.SaveChanges();
            result= "EXITO";
            return new JsonResult(result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = new LogsError();
            error.messag = ex.Message + " --- " + ex.InnerException + " --- " + ex.StackTrace;
            error .datetime = DateTime.Now;
            context.Add(LogsError);
            context.SaveChanges();

            result= "Revise el Logs de Errores";
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

Comment: queres guardar el mensaje de error que ocurre en el try?? o eso es lo que no queres y queres guardar otro mensaje?? eso es lo que no me queda claro

Comment: Quiero guardar el mensaje de error que ocurre en el try! pero al hacerlo en el catch no se porque arrastra el mismo error del try,

Comment: Ocurre el mismo error pq al hacer savechange, dentro del catch se va a tratar de guardar toda la información que has modificado, agregado o eliminado de la bd,  los logs se guardan en ficheros de texto, con un formato que tu entiendas, no los salves en la bd

Answer (score 2):

Mi consejo es que guardes los **logs** en ficheros de texto locales, en la base de datos guarda las trazas, pero los **logs** o excepciones inesperadas guárdalas como ficheros de texto. Los ficheros **logs** se guardan con la extensión ***.log**

Harías algo como esto:

```
try
{
   //Código 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   using(StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(ruta, true))
   {
      logFile.WriteLine(string.Format("Fecha y hora {0}", DateTime.Now));
      logFile.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      logFile.WriteLine("_______________");
   }
}
```

En el **catch** creamos un fichero utilizando la **clase** **StreamWriter** a la cual le pasamos dos parámetros, el primero será un **string** con la ruta y el nombre del fichero, y el segundo parámetro será un **booleano**, que en este caso será **true** para que la información se añada a la que ya habría en el fichero y no sobrescriba la información existente. En caso de existir el fichero simplemente se añadirá la información a el, y en caso de no existir, se creará el fichero, y se añadirá la información correspondiente.

Posteriormente escribimos una línea en el fichero que contenga la fecha y la hora en que ocurrió la excepción. Después vendría otra línea que sería la excepción como tal, y por último imprimiríamos una última línea que serviría como separador de las excepciones.

Para usar la **clase** **StreamWriter** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Podrías usar Serilog.

Comment: @Japv, Gracias por comentar, es muy buena tu sugerencia, la probé y funciona bien, pero no es la respuesta que ando buscando, aun así la coloque como útil Gracias

Comment: @TheOligarch, no sabia que eso existia, estuve mirando y se ve muy bien, la voy a estudiar con mas profundidad :)

Comment: @TheRiddler, y que respuesta buscas, igual se puede mejorar la que te doy

Comment: Mi objetivo es guardar en una tabla cada vez que hay una excepcion, y esto hacerlo dentro del mismo catch

Comment: Te explique que los logs se guardan en ficheros de texto, no en una base de datos

Comment: Revisa tambien lo que dice TheObligarch en su primer comentario, esa libreria parece interesante

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia @TheOligarch, veré esa librería

Comment: @Japv, Los logs también se guardan en una BD

Comment: Socio, tu puedes resolver tu problema como desees, pero los errores generados por las aplicaciones, se guardan en ficheros de texto, con una estructura especifica y extension *.log, y sobre estos ficheros despues puedes usar herramientas de analisis de logs para encontrar determinadas metricas o patrones